# Como iniciar una animacion con MotionScene, MotionLayout automaticamente despues de iniciada una actividad?

Tags: android

Como iniciar la animación automáticamente después de iniciada una actividad sin realizar el evento Click en "tiedt_email"

Quiero iniciar la animación al lanzar la actividad AuthActivity a traves de un Intent, como puedo lograr esto?

**fragment**

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/authFragment"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.login.authFragment.AuthFragment"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/step3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv_logo_auth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img_tag3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiedt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="@string/email"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_email_field"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_recover_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/recover_password"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/ButtonsBackground"
        android:text="@string/Continue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**XML anim code **

```xml
<MotionScene xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- A transition describes an animation via start and end state -->
    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        app:autoTransition="none"
        app:duration="2000">
        <OnClick
            app:targetId="@id/tiedt_email"
            app:clickAction="transitionToEnd" />
    </Transition>

    <!-- Constraints to apply at the start of the animation -->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/imv_logo_auth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/credits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_email_field"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <!-- Constraints to apply at the end of the animation -->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/imv_logo_auth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_email_field"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/credits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_email_field"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: ya sabes como hacerlo? he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro respuesta :(, quiero hacer exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Buenas yo lo hacia con una funcion que tiene el motionlayout que es transitionToEnd, transitionToStart() , para cambiar de transiciones haces setTransition,  estos nombres son de los que usaba antes , toy en react native. Verifica si siguen igual.